# How do I use AppleScript GUI scripting to change the mouse speed?

Tags: applescript, script

I use a Mac at school which resets all settings once logged out. I would like to automatically set some settings in system preferences.

I found an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113316/how-do-i-change-mouse-settings-instantaneously-from-terminal/113320#113320) which described how to change the natural scrolling behavior in system preferences. Unfortunately, this doesn't help in changing the mouse speed. Additionally, I've noticed that fining the checkbox number in AppleScript is a very hit-or-miss process. Checkbox 1 might activate a checkbox at the bottom of a particular settings page, whereas Checkbox 2 might activate one in the middle somewhere. I feel uncertain whether I'd be able to find out how to change a slider due to this 'randomness.'

Does anyone know how to change the slider using GUI scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've no doubt found out, **UI Scripting** has its issues and in this particular case, the *mouse preferences*, the *code* can vary based on the version of the OS and what type of *mouse*, thus making it difficult to provide you *code* that will absolutely work in your use case scenario. To show you, I'll use two examples of *code* that work for me on my system.

On a **MacBook Pro** with an **Apple Magic Mouse** under **OS X 10.8.6** the following *example* **ApplesScript** *code* changes the *value* of the **Tracking** *slider*:

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then ¬
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
delay 1
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "mouseTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        click of radio button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        set value of slider 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences" to 4
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

[image: Apple Magic Mouse preferences]

In a *generic mouse* scenario, the following *example* **ApplesScript** *code* changes the *value* of the **Tracking Speed** *slider*:

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then ¬
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
delay 1
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "mouseTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        set value of slider 3 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences" to 4
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

[image: generic mouse preferences]

---

The *value range* of the **Tracking Speed**  *slider* is a *decimal value* between `0` and `9`. Note that the *value range* for the other *sliders* differ, **Double-Click speed** is `0` to `10`, and **Scrolling Speed** is  `0` to `7`. Also note that these *ranges* may very depending on the OS version and hardware.

With **System Preferences** opened to the **Mouse** *pane*, for a *generic mouse* scenario, use the following line of *code* in **Script Editor** to get the *properties* of the *sliders*:

```
tell application "System Events" to get properties of every slider of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
```

You'll see the *minimum/maximum values* as well as the *value* they are currently set to. The later is important to know after you've manually adjusted to your liking and then use in the *script* to make the changes as wanted.

Note that with **UI Scripting** the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your environment and or additional `delay` *commands* may be necessary as appropriate.

Also note that the *example* **ApplesScript** *code* is coded to first close **System Preferences** if it's open. This is being done so as not to have to see the *events* taking place as the *graphic dance* of some **UI Scripting** can be distracting.

---

You will see the difference between the two versions of *example* **ApplesScript** *code* in the second one, not only does it not have or need the `click of radio button ...` *command*, the `slider` *number* is different, along with its `name`. In the first version it's `slider 1` and `Tracking` where as in the second it's `slider 3` and `Tracking Speed`. There is also no `tab group` in the second version.

To address the *hit to miss* point mentioned in the OP, with the *generic mouse* scenario there are three *sliders*, so the following line of *code* for the *tracking speed*:

```
set value of slider 3 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences" to 4
```

Can be writen as:

```
set value of every slider of window 1 of application process "System Preferences" whose name contains "track" to 4
```

Now you don't need to know what *number* the `slider` is as it will act on the only one whose name contains "track", which in this case will be `slider 3`. The same concept can apply to other `UI elements` too.

You can also address the `slider` by its `name`, e.g.:

```
set value of slider "Tracking Speed" of window 1 of application process "System Preferences" whose name contains "track" to 4
```

The same goes for other **UI elements** that have a `name` *property*, in this case e.g., `window 1` is also: `window "Mouse"`

---

**Note:** The *example* **ApplesScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted. The onus is upon the user to add *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted.